# Is there a way to span a column for a single row in a Kendo Grid?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I wanted to find a way to span a column for only 1 row of data in Kendo Grid for Angular. I looked into using `kendo-grid-span-column` but that seems to do it for every row for the columns specified. I've also looked into using `kendoGridFooterTemplate` but it doesn't seem like there is support for spanning that quite yet. I've posted a picture of an example below:

[image: Example]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post some code or create a simple demo on https://stackblitz.com.

Comment: you are much better off using https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/spreadsheet/index

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by manually adding `colspan` attribute during the data bound event.

See below example for where I use a boolean data field named `isSpecial` to determine if that row needs to be altered:

```
function onDataBound(e) {
  var grid = $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid");

  // Iterate through all the rows
  var rows = grid.items();
  $(rows).each(function (e) {
     var row = this;
     var data = grid.dataItem(row);

     // Check if this row needs to be altered
     if (data.isSpecial) {
        // Set the column span
        $(row).find("td:first-child").attr("colspan", "5");
     }
  });
}
```